# View shiny environment from R console

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way to see the environments created by shiny server from the shiny user in the R console?

I have logged onto the shiny user and used ls() and search() but it doesn't appear that that those environments are visible.

Comment: I think shiny uses the global environment a lot. Maybe try `print(names(globalenv()))`?

Comment: Are you talking about an app running from `shiny-server`, or started from the console with something like `runApp()`?

Comment: Gregor:  I take it shiny-server is run by user shiny by default.  I just don't know if the opensource versions share one R engine between all the processes on the login.

Comment: r2evans:  I'm talking about an app running on `shiny-server`, but being able to 'view' the environment from an R console somewhere.  I imagine it might not be possible, as I see many other methods for debugging, including looking at the logs in `/var/log/shiny-server`